# Fire action method from the view razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a beginner in MVC and web programming. I'm using MVC4 pattern design in my project.

At some point I get callback in view page, from some server and I want the view page to fire action method associated with the view.

I found a lot of examples in google but all examples that I found do not fit me because all methods are called after the user make some action such as clicking on the button. In my case action method should be called automatic, immediately after postback.

Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and perhaps provide an example of what you've already done?  It's not clear right now if you're trying to call the code server-side or client-side.

Comment: Are you meaning like @Html.RenderPartial("View", Model) or @Html.Action("Action")? Very vague question....

Comment: I apologize for the bad formulation of my question.
I need to implement a redirection from a view page to action method in controller.